# Template meta-magic

Tags: c++, templates

I recently came across a kind of dispatch pattern based on the "concepts" of the data types (I think that's the correct use of the term concepts, if not, attributes??).

It seems to me to be a bit more involved than the type of thing I've seen before, and before optimisation at least, introduces temporary variables and function calls. My question is (1) does it all actually get optimised away?? (2) is this the "best" way of doing this kind of type based dispatch??

The code I was reading dealt with iterator types, so I'll stick with that as an example of the pattern. The function `iter_kind` below takes a variable of any type and returns a dummy variable of a particular "concept" type. Something like `random_access_iterator_kind`, or if `_Iter` was a non-iterator type `null_iterator_kind`.

```
template <typename _Iter>
    INLINE_CALL typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::iter_kind iter_kind(_Iter&)
{
    typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::iter_kind _ret;
    return ( _ret );
}
```

It works using the usual meta-magic via specialisation of the `iterator_traits` class. I'm happy with all that stuff.

`iter_kind` gets used to delegate to different implementations of a particular function, as an example:

```
template <typename _Iter, typename _Pred>
    _Iter binary_search(_Iter head, _Iter tail, _Pred pred_less)
    {
        binary_search_impl(head, tail, pred_less, iter_kind(head));
    }

template <typename _Iter, typename _Pred>
    _Iter binary_search_impl(_Iter head, _Iter tail, _Pred pred_less,
                             random_access_iterator_kind)
    {  // actual implementation...
    }

template <typename _Iter, typename _Pred>
    _Iter binary_search_impl(_Iter head, _Iter tail, _Pred pred_less,
                             bidirectional_iterator_kind)
    {
        assert(false);  // can't do bin search without random access iters!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this stuff really does all get optimized away. Compilers are written specifically to get rid of this gunk after it's done, because it's a common trick. Functions and overloading this way are done because, well, it's simply a lot easier than doing it any other way. This is a common trick used in the implementation of the Standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, it's not the best way. You can select the correct overload at compile time like this, for example:

```
 template <typename _Iter, typename _Pred>    
   _Iter binary_search(_Iter head, _Iter tail, _Pred pred_less)    
   {        
     binary_search_impl(head, tail, pred_less,
      std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category());    
   }
```

Even better way is to use SFINAE in the signature of the actual function, with zero overhead at run-time: basically you'd use `std::enable_if` on either iterator category to tell the complier which overload to pick.

Comment: What he's posted up above *is* the inner workings of the Standard library.